# How to pass a big (60+) amount of variables to an HLSL pixel shader?

Tags: c++, directx11, hlsl, fragment-shader

I am in trouble at trying to pass a big amount of variables needed for my pixel shader computations.

After trying and failing to link my struct to a cbuffer (data alignement mismatch) I tried passing my variables first to the vertex shader (with an `D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC` / `CreateInputLayout`) with the intent to link them to the pixel shader through semantics but I hit the 32 shader inputs limit.

I am really stuck (and quite a noob at DX). What is a common / standard way to do this ? Can I only rely on a cbuffer ? Is creating a `D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC` / `CreateInputLayout` even possible for the pixel shader ?

Example struct I want to pass to my pixel shader :

```
struct SceneParamsInterface {
    bool DEAOEnabled;
    XMFLOAT4 DEAOColor;
    double DEAOPow;
    bool lightEnabled;
    XMFLOAT4 lightColor;
    XMFLOAT3 lightDirection;
    bool lightMultiply;
    double lightMultiplyFactor;
    bool ambiantLightEnabled;
    XMFLOAT4 ambiantLightColor;
    bool HSEnabled;
    int HSSpread;
    bool fogEnabled;
    XMFLOAT4 fogColor;
    double fogDistanceMax;
    bool glowEnabled;
    XMFLOAT4 glowColor;
    double glowRadius;
    XMFLOAT4 skyColor;
    bool skyBoxEnabled;
    //uniform sampler2D skyBoxTexture;
    int skyBoxScheme0; // top
    int skyBoxScheme1; // left
    int skyBoxScheme2; // front
    int skyBoxScheme3; // right
    int skyBoxScheme4; // back
    int skyBoxScheme5; // bottom
    int skyBoxRotate;
    double skyBoxRotateSpeed;
    XMFLOAT3 skyBoxRotateAround;
    bool orbitTrapsEnabled;
    int orbitTrapsId;
    XMFLOAT4 objectColor;
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you tell us what the parameters are that you are passing and what you are doing with them in the shader?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711763/hlsl-float-array-packing-in-constant-buffer

Comment: @AlanWolfe I didn't write the pixel shader code yet (I am porting GLSL code to HLSL) but I need all these variables (63+) available in my pixel shader for raytracing computation. I have 4 C++ structs for that purpose - see the one I posted up there.

Comment: Seeing nobody answered yet - I dont know much about dx11, but if you used openGl you could use texture or a buffer where usually geometry is stored.

Comment: I know I started with OpenGL and uniform bindings but went to DX ;) Anyways I could fix my issue at using a cbuffer instead with proper alignement. I used to fail it but found the culprit.

Comment: This is the classic "Direct3D 9" design where you had to use a global set of constants. This is an extremely inefficient way to use Direct3D 11 Constant Buffers. See [Windows to Reality: Getting the Most out of Direct3D 10 Graphics in Your Games](http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/0/4/a04deeb2-d7e2-42a5-984a-9ea5c92bfeb2/Windows%20to%20Reality%20-%20Getting%20the%20Most%20out%20of%20Direct3D%2010%20Graphics%20in%20your%20Games.zip)--yes this is a Direct3D 10 era talk but it 100% applies to Direct3D 11 too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use several constant buffers and group variables together based on how often they change.

If your variables are fairly static ( or just huge ) you may be better off converting values into a texture and extracting them in the shader.